# Terminal command launched from desktop file fails mid-process

Tags: terminal

I want to create a .desktop file that let's me launch the `passwd` command in a terminal. Here's the contents of the .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Password
GenericName=passwd
Comment=Change jeff's password through the terminal
Keywords=password;change;
Icon=org.gnome.Passbook
Terminal=true
Exec=x-terminal-emulator -t "Enter Current Password" --geometry=50x3+670+400 -e sudo passwd jeff /
NotShowIn=GNOME;KDE;XFCE;MATE;
StartupNotify=true
Categories=System;
```

The entry appears in my jgmenu. When I click it, the default terminal opens. The terminal window has the correct title and geometry. It prompts me for my password, which tells me it's attempting to run the `sudo passwd jeff` command.

But when I type my password and press Enter, the terminal window goes away. It won't let me enter my new password and complete the process. The terminal just disappears.

I did try modifying the Exec line to `bash -c "-terminal-emulator -t "Enter Current Password" --geometry=50x3+670+400 -e sudo passwd jeff /"`.  Also, I've tried lxterminal and gnome-terminal; the latter with and without the "keep alive" option. No luck.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If `jeff` is your user, there is no need to use `sudo`. Just run `passwd`. Or are you trying to set the password of a different user?

Comment: In order to prevent automated attacks,  `sudo` and `passwd` try to ensure that their STDIN is, in fact, a human-operated terminal. You're not providing that.

Comment: Unless `/` is required by the syntax of the .desktop file or this `Exec=x-terminal-emulator` (I genuinely don't know), it shouldn't be there. `passwd jeff /` is a wrong usage of `passwd`. Are you sure you need the `/`?

Comment: @Panki, Yes, 'jeff' is my user. I tried your suggestion and it worked.  Thank you!  I also removed the trailing '/' character from my command as Kamil Maciorowski said, so maybe that was the reason.  I'm not sure, but thank you both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you've provided is syntactically and semantically wrong:

> ```
> sudo passwd jeff /    # Wrong
> ```

Since you are `jeff` you don't need root (administrator) privileges to change your own password, nor do you need to specify your own user account as the target. The trailing `/` is an error.

Simply use this instead:

```
passwd
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Chris Davies.  That's exactly what I needed.